# Accessing S3 bucket from script, without reconfiguring the AWS CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, cyberduck

When I want to access my S3 bucket using boto3, I simply do this:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='[bucket name]',
    Prefix='[prefix]'
)
```

But what if I need to access another S3 bucket (not mine but from a client) in another server (using this term as using Cyberduck I can access that S3 having `Server = bucket/prefix.s3.amazonaws.com)`?

[see cyberduck config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zys04.png)

This solution doesn't seem to be working:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='[other access key]',
    aws_secret_access_key='[other secret key]')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='[bucket name]',
    Prefix='[prefix]'
)
```

I can access that S3 using Cyberduck without problems (specifying Server, Access Key ID and Secret Key ID), but on script I get `access denied`.

I tried specifying any other region adding `region_name='[region]'` to boto3.client, but apart from access denied, the other error I got sometimes was `An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.` Which doesn't make much sense, because it's the same used in Cyberduck and by bash scripts, following format:

```
SOURCE_FOLDER=s3://bucket/prefix
SEC_KEY=[other secret key]
ACC_KEY=[other access key]
```

Also using Postman, I don't have any issue, using `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/?prefix=path` and using AWS Signature as Authorization Type.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such notion as servers in the s3 service, bucket are stored per region but are globally accessible because they share a unique global namespace.

*EDIT: You can access them either by using the path-style(https://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[prefix]/file) or the virtual-hosted style(https://[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[prefix]/file)*

**NOTE: On all following examples the credentials are set through environment variables.**

So you can access your prefix by globally:

```py
globally = boto3.client('s3').list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='<my-bucket>', 
    Prefix='<my-folder>'
)
```

<s>Internally `boto3` set the `endpoint_url` to `s3.amazonaws.com`</s>

You can also access your prefix by specifying the region(if you know it):

```py
by_region = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1').list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='<my-bucket>', 
    Prefix='<my-folder>'
)
```

<s>Internally `boto3` set the `endpoint_url` to `s3.<region_name>.amazonaws.com`</s>

And finally you can access your folder by specifying the bucket endpoint:

```py
by_endpoint = boto3.client(
    's3', endpoint_url='https://<my-bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com'
).list_objects_v2(Bucket='<my-bucket>', Prefix='<my-folder>')
```

*The `endpoint_url` can also be `https://<my-bucket>.s3.<region_name>.amazonaws.com`, and the result will be the same.*

This can be validated by running:

```py
assert globally['Contents'] == by_region['Contents'] == by_endpoint['Contents']
```

You can't set the Prefix in the `endpoint_url` only the bucket. 
Since the `Bucket` arguments is required, specifying the `endpoint_url` seems unnecessary to me.

Accessing the bucket globally works, but you may encounter some problem on specific region, see [this comment on a boto3 issue](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/424#issuecomment-68394401).

*EDIT: Since AWS [plan to deprecate path](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/) style URL, with boto3 the endpoint is always set using the the virtual-hosted style. If the region is specified the endpoint end up being `https://<my-bucket>.s3.<region_name>.amazonaws.com`.
Otherwise boto3 start by using a global endpoint ``https://.s3.amazonaws.com`but add the configured default region to the request, in case of a mismatch, the s3 service will return a 400 error with the a message like`
The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-central-1'`.
Which will then force the client to retry the request with a virtual-hosted style regional endpoint anyway. So you'll pay(performance-wise) the round trip each time.*

**So the best solution IMHO is to always instantiate the client with the bucket region.**

Answer (score 0):

These could be 2 possible solutions.

1. Giving **cross-account access** to the S3 bucket in another account. In this case, you **don't have to create a separate S3 client** for the other bucket.
   Reference: [How can I provide cross-account access to objects that are in Amazon S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)
2. Creating a **separate S3 client for the other bucket**. In this case, you **don't need to specify *endpoint_url*** while creating the S3 client assuming the access keys used for the IAM user already has access to it.
   Code Reference:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='[other access key]', aws_secret_access_key='[other secret key]')
```